# Best way to learn Performance Point Services

Tags: performancepoint

I want to know the best book or training course/material to learn about Performance Point services in SP2010.

Answer (score 2):

I use "Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Performance Point Services UNLEASHED"

ISDN: 0672330946

I've used it and it goes into detail not only how to set up your SharePoint server in general, but shows you about Dashboard Designer, KPIs, Reports, Analytics, Managing PPS, Filters, and Security. It has good pictures and walkthroughs.

Answer (score 1):

There are few videos available on Microsoft site:

1- [SharePoint Server 2010 business intelligence insights training -> Module 3 | PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hh126809.aspx)

2- [Up to Speed with PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard-designer-help/up-to-speed-with-performancepoint-dashboard-designer-HA101818158.aspx#_Toc258307094)

These can give you a good start-up, and for further knowledge you can buy the book... I have the e-book link for the book mentioned by Mike, but can't paste it here as policy :P

I hope this helps